# SQL Column to row conversion

Tags: sql, database, pivot

I have a table with the following structure:

```
Col1    Col2
---------------
1        2    
3        4
```

I need to Query in the such a way that the output should be like:

```
ColumnName |  ColumnValue
----------------------------
Col1          1
Col2          2
Col1          3
Col2          4
```

Any help in this will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regarding order, are there any other columns in the table?  Like an `id`?

Answer (score 5):

It's been clarified that the output must be ordered so that it alternates between col1 and col2.  Col1 will always be displayed first, even if col2's value is lower.  This:

```
Col1  |  Col2 
------------
11    |  2 
30    |  42
```

..should return:

```
ColumnName  |  ColumnValue
----------------------------
col1        |  11 
col2        |  2 
col1        |  30 
col2        |  42
```

Effectively, an alternating list based on rank.

It's not clear what database the OP is using.  Assuming MySQL, which has no ranking/analytical functionality you can use:

```
  SELECT x.* 
    FROM (SELECT 'Col1' AS ColumnName,
                 a.col1 AS ColumnValue,
                 @rowcol1 := @rowcol1 + 1 AS rank
            FROM TABLE a
            JOIN (SELECT @rowcol1 := 0) r
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 'Col2',
                 b.col2,
                 @rownum := @rownum + 1
            FROM TABLE b
            JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r) x
ORDER BY x.rank, x.columnname
```

SQL Server 2005+ and Oracle 9i+ support analytic functions, so you can use ROW_NUMBER or RANK:

```
  SELECT x.* 
    FROM (SELECT 'Col1' AS ColumnName,
                 a.col1 AS ColumnValue,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.col1) AS rank
            FROM TABLE a
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 'Col2',
                 b.col2,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY b.col2) AS rank
            FROM TABLE b) x
ORDER BY x.rank, x.columnname
```

Previously, based on the provided example data:

```
SELECT 'Col1' AS ColumnName, 
       a.col1 AS ColumnValue
  FROM TABLE a
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Col2', 
       b.col2
  FROM TABLE b
ORDER BY ColumnValue
```

`UNION ALL` returns all rows, while `UNION` would remove duplicates.

Comment: I can't agree with your formatting but you have 11k so I guess you're doing something right. Nice work

Comment: Sorry folks..this doesnt work.
the 'order by' fetches according to the column value.
I need the col1 and col2 pair values one after another.

Col1    Col2
11        2    
30        42

this query fetches me

col2 2
col1 11
col1 30
col2 42

HOWEVER the output should be 
col1 11
col2  2
col1 30
col2 42

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Col1 INT,
        Col2 INT 
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1,2
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 3,4

SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue
FROM    (
            SELECT Col1, Col2
            FROM    @Table
        ) p
UNPIVOT
    (
        ColumnValue FOR ColumnName IN (Col1, Col2)
    ) upvt
```

Comment: Welcome to 10k - what took you so long? :)

Comment: Thanx man, was trailing you, but you got away. You too fast for me. Thanx any case X-)

Comment: I saw you catching up, so I had to get moving :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the ordering issue from OMG's solution:

```
SELECT 'Col1' AS ColumnName, 
       a.col1 AS ColumnValue
  FROM TABLE a
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Col2', 
       b.col2
  FROM TABLE b
ORDER BY ColumnName, ColumnValue
```