# SQL turn row to column

Tags: sql, crosstab

How can you turn row to column in SQL

```
FIRMA       PSNR    FELDNR  PFLFDNR INHALT  PFGLTAB PFGLTBIS
1           1       013     1       1211111 201111  20111231
1           1       014     2       0,75    2011121 20111111
1           2       013     1       1312312 2011101 20991010
1           2       014     2       1       2011101 20991010
1           3       013     1       666666  2011111 20190101
1           3       014     2       0,925   2011010 20990101
```

should look so: The `psnr` is the key and over `feldnr` `013` or `014` you have different value

```
FIRMA       PSNR   FELDNR  PFLFDNR  INHALT  (Inhalt as FTE) PFGLTAB PFGLTBIS
1           1       013     1       12111111 0,75           201111  20111231
1           2       013     1       1312312  1              2011101 20991010
1           3       013     1       666666   0,925          2011111 20190101
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Possible duplicate of [SQL Convert column to row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560621/sql-convert-column-to-row), [SQL Column to row conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886038/sql-column-to-row-conversion), [Row convert to column in sql server 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687104/row-convert-to-column-in-sql-server-2005), and a few dozen others. Please take the time to search first before posting a question; it gets you answers faster and helps reduce noise and clutter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are asking, but here goes:

```
select a.FIRMA,a.PSNG,a.FELDNR,a.PFLFDNR,a.INHALT,b.INHALT as '(Inhalt as FTE)',
       a.PFGLTAB,a.PFGLTBIS
FROM table a
JOIN table b ON a.FIRMA=b.FIRMA and a.PSNR=b.PSNR AND b.FELDNR='014'
WHERE a.FELDNR='013'
```